# Coefplot-Graph point estimates and confidence intervals from different regressions

Tags: stata, confidence-interval, coefplot

In Stata, I am running the same regression 5 times, with each regression covering a separate time interval. I previously have stored the coefficient of interest after each regression like so:

```
local coef1=_b[x1]
```

I then place all the coefficients in a matrix to graph using coefplot:

```
matrix Z = (`coef1',`coef2',`coef3',`coef4',`coef5',`coef6')

coefplot (matrix(Z), ciopts(recast(rcap)) base vertical noci recast(connected) xlabel(1 "P1" 2 "P2" 3 "P3" 4 "P4" 5 "P5" 6 "P6") yline(0) name(Fig000) xtitle(Time intervals) ytitle(Coefficient)
```

How can I also store and graph the confidence intervals for each point estimate of interest on the same graph?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store CIs depends on the command you use to run your regression.

Many regression commands will produce a matrix called `r(table)`, which will include the CIs. You can then save the matrix and/or access elements of it, including the point estimate and CIs.

Some regression commands do not produce `r(table)`. In this case, you can calculate your CIs directly from the point estimate (`_b[x1]`), standard error (`_se[x1]`) and degrees of freedom (`e(df_r)`), which can all be accessed after the regression. So for example for storing 95% CIs after the regression:

```
local lower = _b[x1] - invt(e(df_r),0.975)*_se[x1]
local upper = _b[x1] + invt(e(df_r),0.975)*_se[x1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! My apologies for the delay.
How would I link the particular CI stored here to my coefficients within Coefplot?
Would expanding matrix Z to store the respective regression's estimates in a column work?

Comment: I don't use `coefplot` when plotting from saved results in matrices (I save the matrices into data using `svmat` and plot from there using normal `twoway` commands; this is another option you may want to try) but the `coefplot` help file suggests that you should add the CIs as *rows* to your matrix Z, so for example if your matrix then has `coef1 coef2 coef3` in row 1, `lowCI1 lowCI2 lowCI3` in row 2, and `uppCI1 uppCI2 uppCI3` in row 3, you can do something like `coefplot matrix(Z[1]), ci((Z[2] Z[3]))`.

Enter `help coefplot` and then see example under "Plotting results from matrices"